# Separating characters using Python Parser of Field Calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, python-parser, splitting, string

How can I separate the characters of a string, for example, three by three with slash letters or dashes and insert them in the Attribute table in ArcMap?

```
abc-def-gh
a100-b200-c300
```

Comment: Use a little python in the field calculator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096105/1446289

Comment: I dont understand, first line is three chacter, second  line is 4

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the field with the text you want to separate is named "THE_TEXT" just for the sake of the example, in the field calculator use the following expression

```
"-".join([ !THE_TEXT![i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(!THE_TEXT!), 3)])
```

[image]

[image]

Obviously you will need to change "THE_TEXT" to your actual field name.

Note you should test this by updating a different field e.g "SEPARATED_TEXT", so "THE_TEXT" remains unchanged. You can always re-run the calculation once you are happy it works correctly